# Why does lodash sorting reverse in an array?

Tags: lodash

I'm using `lodash`, and here's some sample code:

```
var stuff = [{a: 100}, {a: 90}];

var res1 = _.sortBy(stuff, function(st) {
    return [st.a];
});

var res2 = _.sortBy(stuff, function(st) {
    return st.a;
});



console.log(res1);
console.log(res2);
```

This returns:

```
[{a: 90}, {a: 100}]
[{a: 100}, {a: 90}]
```

Why does it switch when an array is returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sort by multiple columns

```
_.sortBy(data, ['key1', 'key2']);
```

Answer (score 4):

The sorting callback doesn't expect an array to be returned (why would it?) so it implicitly converts it to a string. Strings are sorted in alphabetical order. In this specific case, 9 is greater than 1, therefore "90" is greater than "100".

Comment: How would I do sort by multiple columns then?

Comment: I had a feeling this would be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). That's a different question, but you would pass an array of sorting functions to `_.sortBy()`, one for each column.

Comment: @Shamoon check my answer